# Cannot install/update packages. Pantheon Files error

Tags: updates, apt

As the title says, I cannot install or update any packages, either from console via apt-get nor in the AppStore.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pantheon-files : Depends: libpantheon-files-core0 (= 
0.3.4+r2557+pkg63~daily~ubuntu0.4.1) but 
0.3.4+r2561+pkg63~daily~ubuntu0.4.1.1 is installed
              Depends: libpantheon-files-widgets0 (= 
0.3.4+r2557+pkg63~daily~ubuntu0.4.1) but 
0.3.4+r2561+pkg63~daily~ubuntu0.4.1.1 is installed
```

I've tried `apt-get -f install` `apt-get -f upgrade` and a few others and still no results.

Comment: Did you install any PPA?

Comment: This seems like a bug that cropped up late last week. I'm getting the same output from `apt-get dist-upgrade` and `apt-get -f install` does not clean it up. DISTRIB_ID="elementary" DISTRIB_RELEASE=0.4.1 DISTRIB_CODENAME=loki DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki" 4.4.0-77-generic

Comment: No, just the updates from the store. I only noticed when I went to install new packages via `apt`